# How can I print all array elements after a specific one in Java?

Tags: java, arrays

Let's suppose I have an array `String args[]` with a certain amount of elements.
Let's say it goes to up to `args[100]`. I want to print all the elements of `args[]` above `args[5]`.
I don't want to do `System.out.println(args[6] + args[7] + args[8] + args[9] + args[10]);` and etc and etc.
I was wondering if there is a cleaner and more efficient way to print all of those array elements.
Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use a simple `for-loop`:

```
for(int i = 6; i < args.length; i++) System.out.print(args[i]);
```

Comment: What if I want to do it all in the same line?

Comment: @vPrototype this does the job since I used ``.print``

Answer (score 0):

You need a loop.

In your case, assuming a modern JDK I'd use stream and lambdas:

```
Arrays.stream(arr)
  .skip(5)
  .forEach(System.out::println);
```

For loop, probably the most common, certainly in older codebases without lambdas and streaming:

```
    for(int i = 5; i< arr.length; i++) {
        System.out.println(arr[i]);
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use [`IntStream#range`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/stream/IntStream.html#range-int-int-) as shown below:

```
IntStream.range(5, arr.length).forEach(i -> System.out.print(arr[i]));
```

**Demo:**

```
import java.util.stream.IntStream;

public class Main {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        String arr[] = { "a", "b", "c", "d", "e", "f", "g" };
        IntStream.range(2, arr.length).forEach(i -> System.out.print(arr[i]));
    }
}
```

**Output:**

```
cdefg
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use [`dropWhile`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/11/docs/api/java.base/java/util/stream/IntStream.html#dropWhile(java.util.function.IntPredicate)) method that returns:

> ...a stream consisting of the remaining elements of this stream after dropping a subset of elements that match the given predicate.

Example:

```java
int[] arr = {1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9};

Arrays.stream(arr).dropWhile(i -> i != 5).forEach(System.out::print); // 56789
```